# Swift 3 '[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?' is not convertible to '[String : NSString]'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TVOS app that has been converted form Swift 2 to Swift 3 and I am getting the following error.  I am unsure how to silence it.

'[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?' is not convertible to '[String : NSString]'

It is showing up in this piece of code

```
appControllerContext.launchOptions["BASEURL"] = AppDelegate.TVBaseURL

        if let launchOptions = launchOptions as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for (kind, value) in launchOptions {
                appControllerContext.launchOptions[kind] = value
            }
        }
```

[image]

ADDED:

```js
/*
Copyright (C) 2015 Hani Hamrouni. All Rights Reserved.


*/

import UIKit
import TVMLKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, TVApplicationControllerDelegate {
    // MARK: Properties
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    var appController: TVApplicationController?
    
    //change the link to your host url
    
    static let TVBaseURL = "http://google.com"
    
    static let TVBootURL = "\(AppDelegate.TVBaseURL)js/application.js"

    // MARK: UIApplication Overrides
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        /*
            Create the TVApplicationControllerContext for this application
            and set the properties that will be passed to the `App.onLaunch` function
            in JavaScript.
        */
        let appControllerContext = TVApplicationControllerContext()
        
        /*
            The JavaScript URL is used to create the JavaScript context for your
            TVMLKit application. Although it is possible to separate your JavaScript
            into separate files, to help reduce the launch time of your application
            we recommend creating minified and compressed version of this resource.
            This will allow for the resource to be retrieved and UI presented to
            the user quickly.
        */
        if let javaScriptURL = URL(string: AppDelegate.TVBootURL) {
            appControllerContext.javaScriptApplicationURL = javaScriptURL
        }
        
        appControllerContext.launchOptions["BASEURL"] = AppDelegate.TVBaseURL
        
        if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
            for (kind, value) in launchOptions {
                appControllerContext.launchOptions[kind.rawValue] = value as AnyObject
            }
        }
        

        appController = TVApplicationController(context: appControllerContext, window: window, delegate: self)
        
        return true
    }
    
    // MARK: TVApplicationControllerDelegate
    
    func appController(_ appController: TVApplicationController, didFinishLaunching options: [String: Any]?) {
        print("\(#function) invoked with options: \(options)")
    }
    
    func appController(_ appController: TVApplicationController, didFail error: Error) {
        print("\(#function) invoked with error: \(error)")
        
        let title = "Error Launching Application"
        //error message
        let message = error.localizedDescription
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:.alert )
        
        self.appController?.navigationController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
            // ...
        })
    }
    
    func appController(_ appController: TVApplicationController, didStop options: [String: Any]?) {
        print("\(#function) invoked with options: \(options)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried changing `[String: AnyObject]` with `[NSObject: AnyObject]`?

Comment: Yes I have, that does not silence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better work with `[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]` as it is.

How is this?

```
    if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
        for (kind, value) in launchOptions {
            appControllerContext.launchOptions[kind.rawValue] = value
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATED**

Seems the type of the property `launchOptions` of `TVApplicationControllerContext` is `[String: Any]`, so you have no need to cast with `as AnyObject`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have added all the contents of the app delegate file in my question.

Comment: @JasonP., thanks for updating your question and sorry for my ignorance about TVML apps. I'll update my answer but you can find the same code in the template project for TVML app created with the latest Xcode.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code please and tell me what happen.

```
appControllerContext.launchOptions["BASEURL"] = AppDelegate.TVBaseURL

        if let launchOptions = launchOptions as? [String: Any] {
            for (kind, value) in launchOptions {
                appControllerContext.launchOptions[kind] = value
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however this does not silence the error.