# NSKeyValueChangeKey type casting error in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I've been trying to migrate to Swift 3 from 2.3 and after having read all SO [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506804/swift-3-uiapplicationlaunchoptionskey-any-is-not-convertible-to-string), and couple of them showing a similar error but not exactly the same but I've not been able to solve this error.

**'[NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]' is not convertible to '[String : Int]'**

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        guard let changeKeys = change  as? [String: Int] else {
            print("changeKeys  failed")
            return
        }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally what the error was telling me and solved the problem with change the type. I believe in Swift 2.x it was a string type.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        guard let changeKeys = change  as? [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Int] else {
            print("changeKeys  failed")
            return
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 the `change` parameter contains a dictionary with predefined `NSKeyValueChangeKey` keys

- `indexesKey`
- `kindKey`
- `newKey`
- `notificationIsPriorKey`
- `oldKey`

The corresponding value is the changed object. For example

```
if let foo = change?[.newKey] as? Int
```

Comment: So no guard statement anymore? Sometimes I don't know if they are making Swift better or worse. This is as much typing as ObjC!

Comment: `If let` or `guard let` depending on the needs. In Swift you are supposed to take care more what you are doing so in this case you should know what you are observing.